# Getting single key user input using bash builtin READ

Tags: bash, input, user-input

I used following code to get user input:

```
echo -e $'synchronization is finished. Press any key to continue or Ctrl+C to exit...\n' 
read -rs -n1 key
```

It works properly if the user press a space or a letter key. But if the user press one of arrow keys or some other non-printing keys, It seems that `READ` interprets them as two or three characters and thus it uses those extra characters for future `read` calls, i.e. in the next `read` it does not wait for user input.

I tried using `-a` option (`read -rs -n1 -a key`), but no success!

Comment: The arrow keys *are* multiple characters/bytes. Run `cat -v` and hit an arrow key to see what I mean.

Comment: @EtanReisner I know this, but I need a solution that interprets a key as a single key, not as its equivalent characterS!

Comment: Then I believe you need something that can read until it gets a complete escape sequence. Something that actually understands the current terminal/etc. Something like readline or [libtermkey](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/libtermkey/) or similar.

Comment: @EtanReisner: or `getch` from ncurses

Comment: @PHPLearner:  read `man termios` to understand the way that keyboards work.